# Find the functions in a JNI Shared Library?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

Does anyone know how to show all of the functions available via an NDK compiled shared library with public facing JNI functions / methods?

I have a lib***jni.so file which I need to access its methods. Using nm -Dg lib***jni.so outputs all of the symbols found within the Shared Library. I'm only looking for the ones defined as JNI hooks.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few tricks you could use to find this out.

1. **Inspect the corresponding .class files.** If you have the .class files for the library, you can open them up in Eclipse and search for the `native` keyword to see which methods that have been declared to be implemented in native.
2. **Use the `strings` command to dump all strings.** Unless the library does runtime concatenation of Java method names etc (unlikely) you should be able to list most Java methods and classes referenced from the .so with `strings`. Using regexps, you can filter out the interesting strings. For example will `strings lib*jni.so  | grep 'L[^;]*;'` list all classes referenced from the .so (for example `Lcom/somecompany/project/SomeClass;`). It will probably be tricky to match methods with classes, but depending on your needs this maybe is enough.
3. **Build a version of the Dalvik VM that prints a logcat message everytime a native method is registered.** This is the most advanced and time consuming but the most accurate. Simply follow the instructions at http://source.android.com/source/index.html to build an Android emulator, but before you build, enable the debug print at the end of `dvmRegisterJNIMethod` in [dalvik/vm/Jni.cpp](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/blob/master/vm/Jni.cpp) so it becomes: `LOGI("JNI-registered %s.%s:%s", clazz->descriptor, methodName, signature);`

Answer (score 1):

Run `javap` on the .class file with the native methods.